# android listview shadow

Tags: android, android-widget

How can i get rid of the shadow when I scroll `ListView`.

I have shadows appearing on top and bottom of the list.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
<ListView 
   android:fadingEdge="none"
   ...
/>
```

Comment: In code you can do that with setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled and many other methods that control it. Look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: I tried with fadingedge,cache color hind , but nothing worked for me. any other way to disable listview shadow?

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to watch your padding on the ListView. I had a Linear Layout that was in shade at the top and bottom, this was because I had set padding on the layout above and below, so it is crucial that you look at the padding.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8879642/956975), `android:fadingEdge="none"` is deprecated since API Level 14, so rather use `android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

`android:overScrollMode = "never"` works for me.

`android:fadingEdge="none"` didn't work.

See [Remove shadow from top and bottom of ListView or RecyclerView](http://doublewong.com/2015/01/07/2015-01-07-remove-shadow-from-top-and-bottom-of-listview-or-recyclerview/).