# How to remove Fading effect from Listview?

Tags: android

In my application I use a ListView and I need to remove the cacheColorHint at the bottom and top of the list. I tried to set the cacheColorHint to #00000000 but the have semi-transparent effect at the bottom/top.

Do you if it is possible to remove these effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the problem is not with cacheColorHint. Maybe you are trying to deal with fading edge attribute of the listview.

Add this attribute to your listview and check it out,

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

**EDIT**

This attribute is deprecated and will be ignored as of API level 14 (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH). Use `android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"` instead. (from  [Zsolt Safrany's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334270/zsolt-safrany) comment).

Comment: This attribute is deprecated and will be ignored as of API level 14 
 (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH). Use android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp" instead.

Comment: Thanks friend. I will update my answer to reflect your comment. :)

Comment: @Sanket990 did you try android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp" ?

Comment: ya but showing s4 blue fade and Nexus showing black fadding

Comment: Thanks this works. I moved from APK Builder to AIDE and all of a sudden all scrolling views are fading. So I set this attribute as part of my App Theme.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this great article of Romain Guy: http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/22/why-is-my-list-black-an-android-optimization/

However to disable the optimization, simply use the transparent color `#00000000` for the `cacheColorHint`, as you are doing, and set a **solid** background color on the `ListView` to replace its default semi-transparent background.